# Calculation with respect to dates is incorrect in oracle

Tags: excel, oracle, stored-procedures

I have to calculate some `forumales` based on Dates coming from table. For reference the exact value with formula is provided in Excel.

The formula and Excel answer is below.

Formula in Excel :

```
=IF(
  D12>=DATE(2016,10,1),
  (S12-T12)+(S12-T12)*2.5%
  +(
     IF(
       ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(DATE(2016,4,1),D12),0)=0,
       0,
       EFFECT(
         (ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(DATE(2016,4,1),D12),0)*2.5)%,
         ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(DATE(2016,4,1),D12),0)
       )
     )
   )
   *
   ((S12-T12)+((S12-T12)*2.5%)),
   ((S12-T12))
  )
  -(
    IF(
      AND(
        D12>=DATE(2018,4,1),
        D12<=DATE(2018,12,21),
        E12<=DATE(2018,12,21)
      ),
      7.69%*(S12-T12),
      0
    )
  )
```

And the answer for which calculation in Excel is:- 30,153

and my answer coming is 28700/-

The value for `D12 = 03/05/18 (dd/mm/yy) format`, `E12 = 21/04/19`
`S12 = 30000`, `T12 = 2000`,

Here is my calculation logic provided in oracle.

```
IF TO_DATE(V_FINALSRDATE, 'dd-mm-yy') >= TO_DATE('01-10-2016', 'dd-mm-yy')
THEN
v_STD_REVISED_AMT := (V_STANDRD_AMT - v_OD_Discount) + (V_STANDRD_AMT - v_OD_Discount) * 2.5/ 100;
dbms_output.put_line( 'Standard revised amount 1: ' || v_STD_REVISED_AMT);
ELSE
v_STD_REVISED_AMT := (V_STANDRD_AMT - v_OD_Discount);
dbms_output.put_line( 'Standard revised amount 2: ' || v_STD_REVISED_AMT);
END IF;
```

Do I need to add one more IFELS part? Where is my logic failing?

Comment: Your Oracle version only seems to be doing the `(S12-T12)+(S12-T12)*2.5%` part of the formula - which gets the same value. It isn't attempting the `yearfrac` parts? It might be helpful to explain the required logic in English.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Yes, I haven't added the `yearfrac` part in my oracle code. I want to calculate as per the forumales provided in the excel. The answer should match what is their in excel. but currently there is difference in the calculated amount coming from `oracle`.

Comment: Yes, because you're doing a different calculation. `(S12-T12)+(S12-T12)*2.5%` evaluates to 28700, the same as Oracle gives you for that part of the calculation. The `+IF(...)` evaluates to 1453

Comment: okay.. that `+IF...` part, I am unable to convert into oracle formuale. Please help me with that so that I get proper value.

Comment: Your use of `EFFECT` does not make sense as the [`EFFECT` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/effect-function-910d4e4c-79e2-4009-95e6-507e04f11bc4) calculates the effective annual interest rate given a nominal interest rate and a number of periods within the year that the interest will be applied over; however your second argument with `YEARFRAC` is finding the number of full years between two dates, which is nonsensical. I think you need to describe what you are intending to achieve and then we can fix the Excel function and the PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

> Please help as where my logic is failing.

You are not doing the full calculation; you have calculated the `(S12-T12)+(S12-T12)*2.5%` but you have missed the second part of the calculation.

You need to implement an Oracle version of the `YEARFRAC` function using US (NASD) 30/360 day count basis (since you are not passing a 3rd argument to `YEARFRAC`) and then add in the second half of your Excel formula into your PL/SQL calculation.

If you want it to have the same behaviour as Excel then you will also need to implement all the bugs that Excel has as [the documentation notes that](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/yearfrac-function-3844141e-c76d-4143-82b6-208454ddc6a8):

> The `YEARFRAC` function may return an incorrect result when using the US (NASD) 30/360 basis, and the start_date is the last day in February.

However, since the exact nature of the bug is not detailed, you will need to work out what the errors are and implement them yourself. But since you are using a `start_date` of 2016-04-01 then this may not apply (unless you also need to generalise this function for use elsewhere).

Alternatively, since you appear to be rounding the year fraction down to the nearest whole number then you are only calculating the number of full years between the dates and, instead of `YEARFRAC`, you could use:

```sql
EXTRACT( YEAR FROM (V_FINALSRDATE - DATE '2016-04-01') YEAR TO MONTH)
```

Or

```sql
FLOOR( MONTHS_BETWEEN( V_FINALSRDATE, DATE '2016-04-01' ) / 12 )
```

Comment: The exact bug details are :- my calculated value is not as exact as per the excel. I didn't implemented the second and third part as I was unable to prepare the code in oracle.. So please help in creating the code part if u can

Comment: @hud That is not the bug I was referring to; the bug I was referring to is that, in Excel, the `YEARFRAC` function gives inconsistent results when the start date is the last day of February to when it is another day of the year but the documentation does not tell how it is inconsistent; so when a `YEARFRAC` function is implemented in Oracle it would need to reverse engineer the bug in Excel to generate the same results (or else accept that the Excel results may differ). However, I've also given other options to calculate the number of full years between dates.